# find $P\{P\{0\}\}$. $P$ represents the power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm assuming that I'm trying to find the power set of a power set?

I start from the inner power set, $P\{0\}$. $P\{0\}= \{ 0, \{0\} \}$.

Now I do $P\{ 0, \{0\} \}$ which is $\{ 0, \{0\}, \{\{0\}\} \}$.

0 is the empty set.

Is this correct?

So I'm taking it that P{0}={0, {0}, {0, {0}} }

Comment: Do you mean the empty set by "O"?

Comment: hint: $|P(A)| = 2^n$ where $|A| = n$

Comment: Remember the rule : the number of subset of of $A$ is $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of elements of $A$. But the *subsets* of $A$ are the *elements* of $P(A)$. $P(\emptyset)$ has $2$ elements; so it has $2^2=4$ subsets. Those are the elements of $P(P(\emptyset))$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. You forgot one subset of $\{0,\{0\}\}.$ (*Hint*: It isn't proper.)

Comment: so it will be {0, {0}, {{0}}, {0, {0}}} 
could you explain your hint that its not proper?

Comment: $\{0,\{0\}\}$ is a subset of itself, but not a proper subset (since it is equal to itself).

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten $\{0,\{0\}\}$ as an element of $P(0)$.